# Maybe the range of a QTLineEdit inside a QThread that crashes the program?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Thanks for reading this.

I'm making a program to view running processes on *Linux* in a *QTableWidget*.

I am using a *QThread* to update the *QTableWidget*, and I've added filtering with a *QLineEdit*, up to there everything works.

Now I've added access to a SLOT called **killProcessFromLineEdit()** from a button click, but what appends is that I can't access my other *QLineEdit* called **processIdToKill**, it crashes the program without any compilation notice.

I wonder if it is the range of my UI objects that make the program crash when the signal contacts the slot, as the program crashes if I try to reach any Widget from the slot.

I use QtCreator as environment and Linux with C++

The code can be directly browsed or downloaded from :

https://sourceforge.net/p/nicesystemmonitor/code/ci/master/tree/

I've been stuck for a while and it makes me crazy :-)

Patrick

PS : Here's an Image of my debbuger as the problem occurs and the code of my Class where it appends.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8ioM.png

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include "renderprocesstablethread.h"
#include <proc/readproc.h>
#include <proc/procps.h>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
using namespace std;


RenderProcessTableThread::RenderProcessTableThread(QObject *parent)
    : QThread(parent)
{

    restart = false;
    abort = false;
}

RenderProcessTableThread::~RenderProcessTableThread()
{
    mutex.lock();
    abort = true;
    condition.wakeOne();
    mutex.unlock();

    wait();
}


void RenderProcessTableThread::quitRenderProcessTableThread()
{
    cout << "exit thread" << endl;
    quit();
}

void RenderProcessTableThread::killProcessFromLineEdit()
{

    cout << "getProcessIdToKill()->text().length() : " << getProcessIdToKill()->text().length() << endl;
    if (getProcessIdToKill()->text().length() != 0) {
        string s="kill -9 " + getProcessIdToKill()->text().toStdString();
        system(s.c_str());
    }
   statusBar->showMessage(QString((char*)("killed process : " + getProcessIdToKill()->text().toStdString()).c_str()));

}

bool RenderProcessTableThread::isNum(char *s) {
    int i = 0,  flag;

    while(s[i]){
            //if there is a letter in a string then string is not a number
        if(isalpha(s[i]) || s[i] == '.'){
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
        else flag = 1;
        i++;
        }
    if (flag == 1) return true;
    else return false;
}

string RenderProcessTableThread::convertDouble(double value) {
  std::ostringstream o;
  if (!(o << value))
    return "";
  return o.str();
}

string RenderProcessTableThread::convertInt(int value) {
  std::ostringstream o;
  if (!(o << value))
    return "";
  return o.str();
}



void RenderProcessTableThread::run()
{
    linesCount = countProcesses();
    int myTableSize=0;
    ui_tableWidgetProcessus->clearContents();
    while (!abort) {
        mutex.lock();
        mutex.unlock();
        vector<QStringList> myTableList;
        myTableList = fillProcessTable(true);
        myTableSize = myTableList.size();
        // cout << myTableSize << endl;

        // cout << "processIdToKill->text().length() : " << processIdToKill->text().length() << endl;

        /* Checks what lines must be select according to filter */
        for (int row=0; row<myTableSize; row++)
            if (!(myTableList[row].at(0).contains(filterProcessTable->text(), Qt::CaseInsensitive) ||
                    myTableList[row].at(10).contains(filterProcessTable->text(), Qt::CaseInsensitive) ||
                    filterProcessTable->text().length() == 0)) {
                myTableList.erase(myTableList.begin() + row);

                myTableSize--;
                row = -1;

            }

        ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setSortingEnabled(false);
        ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setRowCount(myTableSize);

        /* Fills the Table by either creating items or updating if exists */
        for (int row=0; row<myTableSize; row++)

                for (int column=0; column<11; column++) {
                    if (ui_tableWidgetProcessus->item(row, column) == 0) {

                        /* creates an item */
                        ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setItem(row,column,new QTableWidgetItem(myTableList[row].at(column),0));


                    } else {

                        /* function to get username from */
                        struct passwd *passwd;
                        passwd = getpwuid(getuid());
                        char *userName = passwd->pw_name;

                        /* set colors according to username */
                        if (myTableList[row].at(0).compare("root") == 0 && userName != "root")
                            ui_tableWidgetProcessus->item(row,0)->setBackgroundColor(Qt::red);
                        else if (myTableList[row].at(0).compare(userName) == 0)
                            ui_tableWidgetProcessus->item(row,0)->setBackgroundColor(Qt::green);
                        else
                            ui_tableWidgetProcessus->item(row,0)->setBackgroundColor(Qt::yellow);

                        /* updates an item */
                        ui_tableWidgetProcessus->item(row,column)->setText(myTableList[row].at(column));

                    }
                }

        emit renderedTable();
        sleep(1);

        //cout << "ça tourne" << endl;
    }
    mutex.lock();
    if (!restart)
        condition.wait(&mutex);
    restart = false;
    mutex.unlock();

}
QLineEdit *RenderProcessTableThread::getProcessIdToKill() const
{
    return processIdToKill;
}

void RenderProcessTableThread::setProcessIdToKill(QLineEdit *value)
{
    processIdToKill = value;
}


/* Prepares the process table */
void RenderProcessTableThread::setLocalMainWindow(MainWindow& w)
{
    localMainWindow = &w;
    ui_tableWidgetProcessus = localMainWindow->findChild<QTableWidget*>("tableWidgetProcessus");
    ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setColumnCount(11);
    ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setColumnWidth(10,508);
    ui_ProcessusTabLayout = localMainWindow->findChild<QVBoxLayout*>("verticalLayout_3");
    setProcessIdToKill(localMainWindow->findChild<QLineEdit*>("lineEdit_process"));
    filterProcessTable = localMainWindow->findChild<QLineEdit*>("lineEdit_filter");
    statusBar = localMainWindow->findChild<QStatusBar*>("statusBar");
    QFont fnt;
    fnt.setPointSize(10);
    fnt.setFamily("Arial");
    ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setFont(fnt);
    QStringList labels;
    labels << "user" << "pid" << "cpu" << "nice" << "vsz" << "rss" << "tty" << "stat" << "start" << "time" << "cmd";
    ui_tableWidgetProcessus->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels);
}


int RenderProcessTableThread::countProcesses() {
    PROCTAB* proc = openproc(PROC_FILLUSR | PROC_FILLMEM | PROC_FILLSTAT | PROC_FILLSTATUS | PROC_FILLARG);
    proc_t proc_info;

    memset(&proc_info, 0, sizeof(proc_info));

    int i = 0;
    while (readproc(proc, &proc_info) != NULL) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}


/* Prepares a dynamic table of lists of the different elements to be put in the process table */
vector<QStringList> RenderProcessTableThread::fillProcessTable(bool update) {

    vector<QStringList> myTableList;

    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);

    if (!isRunning()) {
        start(LowPriority);
    } else {
        restart = true;
        condition.wakeOne();
    }

    PROCTAB* proc = openproc(PROC_FILLUSR | PROC_FILLMEM | PROC_FILLSTAT | PROC_FILLSTATUS | PROC_FILLARG);
    proc_t proc_info;

    memset(&proc_info, 0, sizeof(proc_info));

    while (readproc(proc, &proc_info) != NULL) {

        QStringList myLine;
        myLine << QString(proc_info.fuser) << QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.tid).c_str()) << QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.pcpu).c_str())
               << QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.nice).c_str()) << QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.vm_size).c_str()) << QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.rss).c_str())
               << QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.tty).c_str()) << QString(proc_info.state) << QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.start_time).c_str())
               << QString((char*)convertInt(proc_info.stime).c_str());

        string text;
        if (proc_info.cmdline != 0) {
          vector<string> v(proc_info.cmdline, proc_info.cmdline + sizeof(proc_info.cmdline) / sizeof(string));
          text = v[0];
        }
        else {
          vector<string> v;
          v.push_back(proc_info.cmd);
          text = v[0];
        }

        myLine << QString((char*)text.c_str());
        myTableList.push_back(myLine);

    }
    closeproc(proc);

    return myTableList;
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger say? Show us the code where the problem occurs.

Comment: here's the adress of a capture of my debugger, hope it isn't temporary, I couldn't insert images in my post. Here it is : http://i.stack.imgur.com/m8ioM.png

Answer (score 0):

The program has been redesigned, the thread and window were interacting badly, and now everything works okay.

The problem is solved.

Sorry I wasn't clear enough in my first post.

The project working okay can be found at :

https://sourceforge.net/projects/nicesystemmonitor/